# ('HY090' [ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLParamData)')

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to load dataframe in less than a minute, during the process I am getting below error :

('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLParamData)')  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

I used below trail, can someone assist on this.

```
connection = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}; SERVER='+server+';Database='+database+'; 
UID='+User+'; PWD='+Pswd+';'
quoted = quote_plus(connection)
conn = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)
engine = create_engine(conn)


@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True

df.to_sql(name=table_name, schema=schema, con = engine,index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

Pandas version :1.1.0
Sqlalchemy version: 1.3.18
pyodbc version : 4.0.30

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the versions of pandas, SQLAlchemy, and pyodbc that you are currently using.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you and I updated.

Comment: Hey, encountering same error, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, can anybody help?